# Capital characters in Android Project Packagename

Tags: android

I want to use capital letters in android project package name.
So can we use capital letters in package name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why java package name should be in lowercase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-java-package-name-should-be-in-lowercase)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, you should not use capital letters in package name.

You will not be able to build the application with package name having capital letters in MAC and Windows.

So always use small letters for package name.

Comment: This is not true, I use android studio in windows and have a package name with some captial letters. Everything works

Comment: how did you do that help me please @Mike76

Comment: I'm experiencing problems due to capital letters in package name right now, so I wouldn't recommend it as well

Comment: I accidentally published an app with capital letters in the package name, however, I had to remove it and republish it with lower case package name, because I couldn't link the app with AdMob with capital letters.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual package name parts may only start with letters.

For more detailed information, click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can, but trust me you don't want to. Not only does it break convention, it can cause real problems. For example in android, android studio won't support it. This means if you switch IDEs, your code might not compile.

Best practice is to just stick to lower case and convention.