# App working on the emulator but not on actual devices

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have a problem when I try to launch my app in debug mode on actual devices (Galaxy S7 and Galaxy Tab 2 tested). During install, a dialog box appears indicating that the installation has failed with a "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED" error. The error message continues with "`<activity>` doesnot have a valid android:name". Line 23 of the manifest file reproduced below is incriminated (the line corresponds to the line just below the "`<application`" line). As far as I can see, the name I give to my activity is totally correct.

What is even more strange is that, when launched on an emulator, the app get installed and works perfectly...

I can add that the dialog box suggests I should uninstall a previous version potentially installed, but I don't have one, and if I answer to remove it, it fails to uninstall it (which, this time, looks normal).

Any idea about what could cause this problem?

The manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="GL.MesContacts"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26">
</uses-sdk>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="GL.MesContacts.ActivitePrincipale"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="string resource"
        android:name="GL.MesContacts.RecepteurChangementEtatTelephone">

        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>

   </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your package to contain only lower case characters. It must not contain upper case characters. 
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12534322/3162918) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your package name to lower case:

`package="gl.mescontacts"`

Answer (score 0):

as you defined inside your manifest `package="GL.MesContacts"`, activity name should be only `.ActivitePrincipale` like this `<activity
        android:name=".ActivitePrincipale"> 
....
</activity>`

Comment: Already tried, but same result... (receiver's name changed in the same manner).