# Spring boot with neo4j Class class ,,, is not a valid entity class

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Spring boot 2.0.3 with neo4j.

If I create an entity package name with capital letter like `Domain`, it gives me an error message like

> Class class com.Domain.Student is not a valid entity class

But If I define Entity class with `domain`, it is working.

Is Capital letter package is not allow only for Entity package ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally capital letters in package name are not a compatible with Java spec.
[Why should java package name be lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-should-java-package-name-be-lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the standard tells you to use the small letters for naming the package. But that's only a standard, not a compilation error. If you give the capital letter in a package the compiler will allow you to use that. example :

```
    package com.example.demo.Domain;

    public class Student {
      private long id;
    }
```

So I don't think that is your problem if you  provide more code snippets then that will be a good thing to solve it very easily

Comment: Yes I knew it but if you work with spring boot then it not possible to give package name as capital at any way

Comment: Actually, there is no restriction in spring boot. It will allow you to create a package with capital letters. I don't find any difficulties in creating a package with capital letters.

Comment: If you find then send me application link so I download it and test it