# No qualifying bean, but I added @Component annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

> Could not invoke step [User clicks Register on main page] defined at
> 'pcz.StepDefs.LoginPageStepDefs.userClicksRegisterOnMainPage()'. It
> appears there was a problem with the step definition. The converted
> arguments types were ()
>
> Caused by: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Error
> creating bean with name 'pcz.StepDefs.LoginPageStepDefs': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'loginPage'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'pcz.Page.LoginPage' available: expected at
> least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory
> .annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Project Structure:

[image]

```
public class LoginPageStepDefs {

@Autowired
LoginPage loginPage;


    @When("User clicks Register on main page")
    public void userClicksRegisterOnMainPage() {
        loginPage.test();

    }
}



import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class LoginPage {
    public void test(){
    }
}
```

And Spring config:

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringBootCucumberApplication.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}


@SpringBootApplication()
public class SpringBootCucumberApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither your `SpringBootCucumberApplication` nor your `CucumberSpringConfiguration` scan your `LoginPage` component because it's in a totally different package. The default component scan only looks in the current and any descending packages, but `pcz.Page` isn't anywhere beneath the `pcz.StepDefs` or `config` packages.

You can try any of the following:

- Rename the `config` package to `pcz`. That will make the default component scan of your `SpringBootCucumberApplication` notice your `pcz.Page` package.
- Move your `pcz.Page` package to `pcz.StepDefs.Page` so that the default component scan of your `CucumberSpringConfiguration` will notice it.
- Use a [ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation on your `CucumberSpringApplication`, telling it which packages to scan: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"Page"})`.

Side note, your package names [should probably be lower-cased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534302/why-should-java-package-name-be-lowercase).

Comment: I decided to rename package - works, I'll take a look on names, thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left, that'll show that this question has been resolved.