# Adverse effects of uppercase characters in package name

Tags: android, package

Are there adverse effects of using uppercase letters in my package name? I know I should not do that, but I have already published an app with uppercase letters in the package name.

Should I change the package name to use only lowercase letters?

Comment: I tried to find about this, and I got [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names). You might consider to read the accepted answer and also the comment: Basically, it's acceptable (at that time), but not recommended (in current trend). Atop of that, I don't think there is any side effects for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

If you application runs with no problems, and you don't care much about best practice, then your fine.

But it is best practice to keep the naming of your packages all in lower cases. :-)

You can read more about this at Oracle's documentation on Java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html