# Can we use camel case in java package naming?

Tags: java

For example:
Which of the following package names is correct?

```
com.google.payrolldivision;
```

or

```
com.google.payrollDivision;
```

Please just answer the question without beating around the bush?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Why don't you just try it for yourself and see?

Comment: According to the official docs, looks like it is simply a matter of choice/style to use camel case or not; apparently there's nothing actually prohibitive about it. The specific reason cited by the docs for lower case convention : *"Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces."* .. that's it. I just tested for the following, and it built & ran fine package `com.abc.activity.navDrawer;`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Please just answer the question

OK, then taking your question as a "a xor b", the answer is

```
com.google.payrolldivision;
```

as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html.

However, your title and post ask two very different questions, so it's hard to "just answer **the** question".

Comment: Careful, you're on the verge of beating around the bush...

Comment: @shmosel Haha good one!

Comment: I tried really hard not to :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the Oracle [webpage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), you should write your package name in lowercase.

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.