# How to add "requires" for artifact having "-"(hyphen) in its name

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I've included these dependencies in my Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to add this dependency in module-info.java like so:

```
module io.github.wildcraft.restclient {
    requires httpcore; // no compilation problem
    requires httpclient; // no compilation problem
    requires commons-io; // shows compilation error
}
```

For commons-io, I receive a compilation error. How can I make this work?

Comment: You could always use an underscore instead. Hyphens are not allowed in package/module names. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names).

Comment: You mean to rename the artificat in the local repository ?

Comment: You would have to rename it in some way.

Comment: You should submit that as a bug to Apache

Comment: The (maven) group id name is not necessarily the same as the (java) module name. They are separate concepts with different restrictions for their names.

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules Mentions that automatic module names are derived from jar names (which I assume you are using?), just not _how_. Could try `commons.io`

Comment: @JornVernee here: http://download.java.net/java/jigsaw/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of-java.nio.file.Path…​- look for `of`

Comment: @JornVernee , mentioning "commons.io" worked. If you post this as an answer, i can mark it as answered.

Comment: It's mentioned in the javadocs `All non-alphanumeric characters ([^A-Za-z0-9]) in the module name are replaced with a dot ("."), all repeating dots are replaced with one dot, and all leading and trailing dots are removed.`

Comment: @cobra I just guessed correctly, but I didn't have the explanation. I'll leave answering up to someone who does.

Comment: @JornVernee the explanation on how dot works is in the javadoc for `java.lang.module.ModuleFinder` I linked above

Comment: `mvn dependency:resolve` will show you the module name per dependency when running with Java 9

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Short Version

Use `requires commons.io`. (In general, see [nullpointer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393846/2525313) how to learn a module's name.)

## Long Version

Since `commons-io.jar` is not yet modularized, you are creating an automatic module, for which the module system has to come up with a name. The [Javadoc of `ModuleFinder`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of-java.nio.file.Path...-) describes how that happens:

> The module finder returned by this method supports modules packaged as JAR files. [...] A JAR file that does not have a `module-info.class` in its top-level directory defines an automatic module, as follows:
>
> - If the JAR file has the attribute "Automatic-Module-Name" in its main manifest then its value is the module name. The module name is otherwise derived from the name of the JAR file.
> - The version and the module name [...] are derived from the file name of the JAR file as follows:
>
>   - [...]
>   - All non-alphanumeric characters ([^A-Za-z0-9]) in the module name are replaced with a dot ("."), all repeating dots are replaced with one dot, and all leading and trailing dots are removed.

The last two bullets apply to automatic modules that are not prepared for Java 9, e.g. to `commons.io`. This example from the same Javadoc explains what happens in your case:

> - As an example, a JAR file named "foo-bar.jar" will derive a module name "foo.bar" and no version. A JAR file named "foo-bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar" will derive a module name "foo.bar" and "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT" as the version.

Hence `requires commons.io` should work.

Comment: with the latest version you can use `requires org.apache.commons.io;`

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the shorter version of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393083/1746118) provided by Nicolai. In order to find out the module name of the dependencies(jar) used in your project, you can use the [jar tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#JSWOR614) from command line.

```
jar --file=<jar-file-path> --describe-module
```

Since these would be understood as an *automatic module* by the tool, the output would be somewhat like:-

> ```
> $ / jar --file=commons-lang3-3.6.jar --describe-module
> No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.
>
> org.apache.commons.lang3@3.6 automatic // this is what you need to use without the version
>
> requires java.base mandated
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.arch
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.builder
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.event
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.exception
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.math
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.mutable
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.text
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.time
> contains org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple
> ```