# Java module found in both source and doc jars

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I trying to convert Ice build to use Java modules, we build source and doc JARs along the main jars and put all of them in a lib directory

When I try to use the new modules setting --modules-path to the lib directory, I getting errors related to same module found in the main jar and the doc jar.

```
java --describe-module com.zeroc.ice --module-path lib
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Two versions of module icestorm found in lib (icestorm-3.7.2.jar and icestorm-3.7.2-javadoc.jar)
```

Is there something I can do to avoid this kind of conflict, or should I Just not be putting the doc and sources JAR files in the lib directory along the main JARs.

Comment: By the names of those `jar`s, just have `icestorm-3.7.2-javadoc` there in the `lib` folder. Assuming it means including all class(from the `icestorm-3.7.2` jar) as well as javadoc generated jar. Cause: Both these modules are ending up with same module name(mostly automatic modules) in the module-path. You can try out the `jar` tool on individual jars to [describe modules for those jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393846/1746118) and confirm the same.

Comment: My concern is just that I'll not be able to use `--module-path lib` for build applications, I guess I will have to move the sources and doc jars to separate folder if I want to do that

Comment: ... or if these are automatic modules, you can rename the `icestorm-3.7.2-javadoc` to `icestorm-javadoc-3.7.2`, should work I believe.