# Naming conventions of composed package names

Tags: java, package, naming-conventions

I want to create a package named `form validator`.

Is it better to write

- `form_validator`,
- `formValidator` or
- `formvalidator`?

I want to mention that I want to **avoid** `form.validator`. And that `form-validator` is **forbidden**.

Comment: `com.company.form.validator`?

Comment: in fact I want to avoid form.validator

Comment: Should be lower case to [avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Comment: Might help plenty: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179277/9192223

Comment: I think `formvalidator` is the most conventional.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid form.validator? It should be understand as two packages (form and validator). Thats probably the way I would follow.

Comment: tl;dr: smush-case (flat-case) is idiomatic

Answer (score 116, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) on package naming convention:

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces

So this would leave you with the following two possibilities:

```
form_validator
formvalidator
```

Actually the documentation also makes it clear that underscore plays a special role when it appears in package names:

> if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int" ... the suggested convention is to add an underscore.

So, underscore is suggested only in special cases, into which your naming problem does not seem to fall.  So I would recommend `formvalidator` as the package name.

Comment: "*So, underscore is suggested only in special cases*". Even though you may be right, that's not what that documentation says. The Oracle doc text which you are quoting, is **only** talking about how you can make valid package name when a domain name isn't valid as package name, but it does **not** say neither suggest that underscores should **only** be used in special cases. But the answer of @srath does say that this (no undersquares) is a style Google.

Answer (score 50):

The most conventional one would be the 3rd one: `formvalidator`.

The [Google Java Style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.1-package-names) notes:

> **5.2.1 Package names**
>
> Package names are all lowercase, with consecutive words simply concatenated together (no underscores). For example, `com.example.deepspace`, not `com.example.deepSpace` or `com.example.deep_space`.

As @teppic said, the [Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) state that

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

Answer (score 9):

In Java package names are written in all **lower case**. Which means following would be the most ideal packaging name.

```
formvalidator
```

This is also accepted.

```
form_validator
```

Answer (score 5):

Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces. So

- `form_validator` or
- `formvalidator`.

For details see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).