# Naming an android package

Tags: android, android-studio

I just bought a domain like :  **example.in**

Currently the package name looks like this   com.example.myappname

What should I name my android package..

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming conventions of composed package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890803/naming-conventions-of-composed-package-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is suggested that you name it according to a domain you own where you mirror it. So for example if you own **example.in** and you app is called "app" then if it were a url you could have something like *app.example.in* and for an android package you would have `in.example.app`

More details on the package naming convention (see the explanation at the package attribute): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element