# libGDX Project Setup Package Name Doesn't Allow Underscores

Tags: java, libgdx, package, naming-conventions, naming

In a normal Android Studio or Java project, underscores are valid (right?). However, when I attempt to set it up in the libGDX project setup, I am not allowed to use underscores. Is there any workaround to this? (Or is it just a normal package naming convention?)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIdA2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Underscore in package name is valid for LibGDX project setup jar.

You're getting `invalid package name` due to you've Capital letter in your package name.

`gdx-setup.jar` using this [regex](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/f2ed6b4a365922964eb06538f486d9526d1803af/extensions/gdx-setup/src/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/GdxSetupUI.java#L143), for package validation.

Comment: Oh, sorry you are correct. Also, would you recommend using underscores in package names or is it simply just better practice/convention to omit them?

Comment: It's better to go with flow(my recommendation). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179216/what-is-the-convention-for-word-separator-in-java-package-names) thread for more details