# IOS and Android package name

Tags: android, ios, flutter, package

I created demo project in Flutter, and the package name:

```
iOS : com.example.flutterAppTest

Android : com.example.flutter_app_test
```

Why they are different? Should they need to be different?

What is the practice for package names for cross platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [Java package naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) the reason for underscores for the Android package name is:

> ### Naming Conventions
>
> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

For iOS, many people use `camelCase`. The same case was used your iOS bundle ID or package name but there is no strict rule which case to use. This is only a convention and not a compiler rule.

Valid names consist of letters (lower or upper case), digits, underscores and start from a letter or underscore.

**Should they need to be different?**

Each platform follows its own conventions but there is no need for them to be different. As aforementioned - you can rename package as you wish using letters, digits and underscores.

**What is the practice for package names for cross platform?**

If possible - you can use the same package name but it will violate conventions, which is not desirable.

If not possible (e.g. project does not compile) - follow the rules.

IMHO, following conventions (as the also follow the rules) is the best solution.

You can find more information here about [Java package naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179277/7210237) (this is a different resource).